# "Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'content-type'" error in Django view

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm having this problem with this use of the `get_success_url()` in my `CreateView` class:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    search = searchViews.getIndexInstance()
    search.mainfunc(self.contentForSearch, self.discussion.pk)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('discussion-detail', kwargs={'slug':self.discussion.slug}))
```

Here's the complete error stacktrace:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/viewanalyse/discussion/views.py" in dispatch
  30.         return super(LoggedInMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  249.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  215.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/viewanalyse/discussion/views.py" in form_valid
  374.         return super(DiscussionContentUpdateCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  194.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  108.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
File "/home/nithin/djangopro/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  456.             raise DisallowedRedirect("Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol '%s'" % parsed.scheme)

Exception Type: DisallowedRedirect at /discussion/discussion-content-update/why-i-believe-in-reincarnation-g-hijo-2015-08-09-162236316999/
Exception Value: Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'content-type'
```

What's the cause and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

The [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) method should return a **URL**, not an HTTP response.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    search = searchViews.getIndexInstance()
    search.mainfunc(self.contentForSearch, self.discussion.pk)
    return reverse('discussion-detail',kwargs={'slug':self.discussion.slug})
```

It's not clear what the first two lines are for, they don't seem to be used by the `reverse()` call.

Comment: but my question is how do i send a httpResponseRedirect so that the user should not be able to re-submit the form.

Comment: When the form is valid, the `CreateView` will create the object, then automatically redirect to the url that you return in `get_success_url`. You don't need to manually send an `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: Then what should i do so that the user should not be able to press **back** and re submit the form with the previous data or is there any complete solution for forbidding the user from hitting the **back** button.

Comment: There isn't a generic solution to prevent that.